# How to access the window object in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman-pre-request-script

I want to write a simple *Pre-request Script* in Postman that asks for a user confirmation if the request should really be executed.
I think about using

```
var confirmed = confirm("Start request?");
```

or

```
var confirmed = window.confirm("Start request?");
```

But it states "confirm is not defined" or "window is not defined".

Comment: Why would you expect a window object in postman?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4791)

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access to postman window via `javascript` code. But fortunately there is suggestion for the feature.

You can check [this](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4791) to know about the feature and the release time